# Proof that sets containing all their limit points are closed.

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading Topology Without Tears. Its definition of a limit point is:

> Let A be a subset of a topological space (X, τ). A point x ∈ X is said to be a limit point (or accumulation point or cluster point) of A if every open set, U , containing x contains a point of A different from x.

It also offers a proof that:

> if A contains all of its limit points, then it is a closed set.

I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something, but it seemed like the following contradicts this proposition:

Let X = {1, 2, 3} with T = {∅, {1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}} and A = {1, 2}. There are no limit points of A, since both points in A are in open sets not containing any other points in A. Therefore, A contains all of its limit points (a statement which would seem to be true in the case in which A has zero limit points).

If A is closed in (X, T), then by definition A' = {3} is open. Yet as T is defined above, {3} is not open. This therefore appears to be a counterexample to the statement that if a set A contains all its limit points, then it is closed in (X, T).

As a second example, let T = {∅, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}, again with A = {1, 2}. Now, 1 is a limit point of A because all open sets ({1, 2} and {1, 2, 3}) contain 2, another point in A that is not equal to 1. 2 is a limit point of A for the same reason. A contains all its limit points. Yet A is not closed in (X, T) because once again A' = {3} is not in T (is not open).

Again, I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something here, so I'd appreciate anybody who can point out where I'm making a mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set does not contain all its limit points. $3$ is in fact a limit point, in both examples.